# Contour Integration: non-convergent integral

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

The question is 
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2} dx$$

My attempt:
$$I=-\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2ix}-2+e^{-2ix}}{x^2} dx$$

$$I=-\frac{1}{4} \Big[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2ix}}{x^2} dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2} dx +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2ix}}{x^2} dx \Big] $$

Now I use contours as mentioned in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636423/contour-integration-with-pole-on-contour).

If we write 
$$I=-\frac{1}{4}\Big[A+B+C\Big]$$ where $A,B,C$ are the corresponding integrals.

For, $A$, and $C$ they can be worked out using Jordan's lemma and the residue theorem.

I run into a problem with $B$, as it does not converge.
Any ideas?

Comment: Split it differently, $$\frac{e^{2ix} - 1}{x^2} + \frac{e^{-2ix} - 1}{x^2}.$$ Note that your $A$ and $C$ can't be worked out via Jordan's lemma and the residue theorem either, since you have a pole of order $2$ at $0$.

Comment: Hmm, do any of these three integrals converge? You may be seeing the following sort of error. Suppose $f$ is positive and $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\; dx$ exists. Even though $f(x)=(\frac12 f(x)+1)+(\frac12 f(x)-1)$, neither of the integrals $\int_{\mathbb R} (\frac12 f(x)\pm 1)\; dx$ exists, so you can't say $\int_{\mathbb R}  f(x)\; dx=\int_{\mathbb R} (\frac12 f(x)+1)\; dx+\int_{\mathbb R} (\frac12 f(x)-1)\; dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Consider,

$$j(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}\sin^2(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} a^{-1/2} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} e^{-1/a} a^{-1/2}. $$

Now let $J(a)$ be an antiderivative of $j(a)$.

$$ J(a) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a^{1/2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{erf}(1/\sqrt{a})-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sqrt{a}e^{-1/a}+C$$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a^{1/2}\left(1-e^{-1/a}\right) - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{erf}(1/\sqrt{a})+C$$

We can see that,
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} J(a) = C. $$

The definition of $J$ suggests that we can identify it with the integral,

$$ J(a)=-\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x,$$

this integral clearly goes to $0$ in the limit as $a\rightarrow \infty$ so we choose $C=0$.

$$ J(a) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a^{1/2}\left(1-e^{-1/a}\right) - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{erf}(1/\sqrt{a}) $$

---

Now assuming that $J(a)$ equals the integral we get,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x =- \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} J(a)$$
$$ = -\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a^{1/2}\left(1-e^{-1/a}\right) - \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{erf}(1/\sqrt{a})\right),$$

$$ = \pi/2 $$

Answer (score 2):

We can use Parseval's theorem to solve the integral.

The rectangle function is,

$$\Pi(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad |x|<1/2 \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

The Fourier transform of the rectangle function is the $\mathrm{sinc}$ function.

$$ \hat{\Pi}(k) = \mathrm{sinc}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sin(k)}{k}.$$

Parseval's theorem tells us that,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{sinc}^2(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Pi^2(x) dx = \frac12,$$

which gives us,
$$ \boxed{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{sinc}^2(k) = \pi}.$$

Comment: I came up with a more elegant and straightforward solution; or rather Parseval did.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$ \sin^2{x} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{2x}), $$
then
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos{2x}}{2x^2} \, dx. $$
Now, you can either consider this as the real part of $(1-e^{2ix})/x^2$, and then do the contour integral as usual with $(1-e^{2iz})/z^2$ around a circle in the upper half-plane, taking care with the simple pole at $z=0$, or you can integrate by parts:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos{2x}}{2x^2} \, dx = \left[ \frac{1-\cos{2x}}{-2x} \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{2x}}{-x} \, dx, $$
which you've no doubt seen how to do before.

(It's surprising how often people forget you can do that when they're taught to do real integrals using residue calculus! I had a group of students the other day with much the same problem.)